# How can I submit a hash key in an URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I have a Spring-MVC application with Freemarker as the view component.

In my templates, several links are generated which point back to my application and which include URL parameters containing a hash key (`#`).

Example:

parameter: `Q#106368 11`

URL generated by Freemarker with encoded param: `testurl.html?key=Q%23106368%2011`

I use JavaScript to redirect to this URL (reason: I use JS to manage loading of 2 frames at the same time).

The redirect method is simple:

```
    function redir(url) {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

The JS call generated by Freemarker looks like

```
<a href="javascript:redir('http://localhost:8080/testappp/testurl.html?key=Q%23106368%2011');">test</a>
```

My problem is that the browser / Javascript converts back the URL encoded parameter, thinks there is a `#` and cuts off there.

When I use `window.location.href='http://...'` directly it works. Only when using the method parameter it seems to be magically URL decoded and then the redirect fails because the URL gets cut off at the `#`.

Is there an easy way to transmit the parameter correctly?

I am aware that I could replace the `#`, e.g. with `$$$hash$$$`, in the template and do the replacement on the server side again. But there are so many places I would have to change...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Marc B commented, it is necessary to URL encode again. The method would be `encodeURI()`. However, this method does not encode the `#` sign. For my specific use case, I have to replace the `#` sign with `%23` after the encoding.

The redirect JS method finally looks like:

```
    function redir(url) {
        url = encodeURI(url);
        url = url.replace(/#/g, '%23');
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

[Comparing escape(), encodeURI(), and encodeURIComponent()](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)

Comment: Just had this now. As the next answer suggests, just use `encodeURIComponent` instead, it's more thorough and correct than manually replacing. It also encodes other stuff that `encodeURI` doesn't - compare `encodeURI("google.com/pg/#home?param=$#$&*(@=")` with `encodeURIComponent("google.com/pg/#home?param=$#$&*(@=")` and see the difference.

Answer (score 8):

encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent is more thorough than just encodeURI, it will decode/encode '#' and event '/'

Answer (score 2):

What browser are you using? I'm trying FireFox 5 and it doesn't convert `%23` back into `#` in my testing. When you mouse over the link or copy the link location, what does that have? Are you sure whatever is outputting the link isn't doing the conversion?

**Update**

This isn't ideal, but it seems like it solves the problem:

```
<a onclick="url = 'http://localhost:8080/testappp/testurl.html?key=Q%23106368%2011';" href="javascript:redir(url);">test</a>
```

It seems like the `href` attribute is decoded. When I mouse over it I seen the `#` instead of the `%23`.

Comment: Agreed. Any browser that *does* convert this escape back would be a serious piece of crap.

Comment: That is, copy the link location or inspect it directly from code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I took a closer look and I forgot to mention a detail which is very important but I never thought it would be. I use a Javascript redirect method and it happens when I use this method. It works fine when I copy & paste the URL into the browser. So it is not a Java/Spring/browser issue, it is a Javascript issue. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Remember that the escaping/encoding only lasts one trip through the browser. If you're doing a double-trip, then you need to re-encode at each stage.

Comment: @Marc B - if I just have the complete URL string in the JS method, how would I do a proper re-encode. Just adding url = encodeURI(url); does not work for me.