# When trying to access route parameter, I only get part of it and everything after # is cut off

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a component in which the user has to write his Blizzard battle tag which has the following format:

```
DisplayName#1337
```

And on a button click, I execute a function which sends the user to the following URL:

```
www.example.com/user/DisplayName#1337
```

And on that URL, a component extract the parameter like this:

```
displayName: this.$route.params.displayName
```

and then I make a GET request to a URL like this:

```
axios.get('/User/SearchUsers?q=' + this.displayName)
```

Now the problem is that `displayName` only contains what is before the # in the display name. So if the user typed his battle tag `TestTag#1337`, displayName is going to contain only TestTag and #1337 is going to be lost. I assume this happens because the # symbol but how can I avoid this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I submit a hash key in an URL parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627648/how-can-i-submit-a-hash-key-in-an-url-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume this happens because the # symbol but how can I avoid this?

You can't. But you can fix it.

The `$route` object exposes [additional information](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) within given URL, in your case you want the **hash** bit.

Expanding on [Tyler Roper](/q/54055368/#comment94945232_54055368)'s comment, here is the Vue Router approach:

```
computed: {
  displayName() {
    return this.$route.params.displayName + this.$route.hash;
  }
}
```

Gives you for example **TestTag#1337**. If no hash is present the value will be an empty string.

```
// /User/SearchUsers?q=TestTag#1337
axios.get('/User/SearchUsers?q=' + this.displayName);
```

Answer (score 0):

When accessing query parameters you use ? to indicate the first query parameter and & to indicate subsequent parameters

For example

www.mySocialNetwork/membersList?name=MarkZuckerberg&age=21

Parsing the string itself depends on your use case and if you are using a framework or library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

in the most vanilla sense you can store window.location.search

ie. `const params = window.location.search`

and use various methods and libraries to parse the result

https://gomakethings.com/getting-all-query-string-values-from-a-url-with-vanilla-js/

or in most browsers:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
```

Comment: OP is asking why his parameter value is getting truncated at the `#`, and although this advice might be *generally* useful, it doesn't seem to answer the question.